# How could I open a file from a user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to properly use a user input from one function to process data from a file in another function?

What I've tried below is two if conditions. The first if condition works but also returns a none value; while the second if condition is never reached because of the none value. I read in previous posts that the none is returned if you don't specify something specific to be returned. But this leads to further confusion as my getInputFile() returns the user input?

```
def function(afile):

    #connect user input to afile
    if 'somefile.jpg' in afile:
        afile = content1
    if 'somefile2.jpg' in afile:
        afile = content2





def getInputFile():

    ending = '.jpg'
    somefiles = ['somefile.jpg','somefile.jpg']
    #condition that I want to become false
    check = input('Enter filename: ') 
    while ending not in check:
            check = input('Invalid please re-enter: ')
    if ending in check:
        if check in somefiles:
            return check
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open()` takes just any string and tries to open that as a file

`input()` returns a string of whatever you type

Therefore `open(input('give me a filename: '))` will open the filename that you type.

You can move those around to functions, as you see fit, and know that Python doesn't really care about file extensions, just that the name matches exactly with what you are opening (including the extension)

> my getInputFile() returns the user input?

It seems to `return validation` under some condition, yes. When that condition is false, though, you return nothing, therefore `None`. Note that the `fileType in validation` is not needed because that is guaranteed when the while loop is finished.

---

> first if condition works but also returns a none value; while the second if condition is never reached because of the none value

If conditions don't return values, and they are always evalutated